# Is there any way to tell EF tooling to ignore a DbContext unless explicitly targeted?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have created a nuget package with a simple DbContext + Sqlite db that should be self contained and ideally hidden from consumers. The problem is that when adding the package to projects that only have one DbContext class before, the tooling picks up on the new DbContext and requires the --context argument for i.e. migrations. Is there an attribute or similar that can hide the DbContext for the ef tools unless the context is explicitly targeted with the --context argument?

Comment: If you want it hidden from outside your package, can you make it `internal`?

Comment: Use a #IF.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives?force_isolation=true